# symfony 1.4 file uploads and templates

Tags: php, mysql, symfony-1.4

I successfully saved the path of photo into mysql database.My question is,how to render correctly in templates?I tried

```
<td width="129" rowspan="5"><img src= "/uploads/photos<?php echo $applicant->photo?>"width="129" height="129"/></td>
```

Not working.
In my action, i tried

```
$photo = $this->form->getValue('photo');
            $filename = 'photo'.sha1($photo->getOriginalName());
            $extension = $photo->getExtension($photo->getOriginalExtension());
            //$photo->save(sfConfig::get('sf_upload_dir').'/' . $filename . $extension);
            $photo->save(sfConfig::get('sf_upload_dir') . '/'.$photo) . date('Ym') . '/' . $filename . $extension);
```

and in my form i tried

```
 $this->widgetSchema['photo'] = new sfWidgetFormInputFileEditable(array(
    'label' => 'Photo',
    'file_src' => '/uploads/photos/'.$this->getObject()->getPhoto(),
    'is_image' => true,
    'edit_mode' => !$this->isNew(),
    'template' => '<div class="sublabel">%file%<br />%input%<br />%delete% %delete_label%</div>',
));

$this->validatorSchema['photo'] = new sfValidatorFile(array(
    'required'   => false,
    'path'       => sfConfig::get('sf_upload_dir').'/photos',
    'mime_types' => 'web_images',
));
```

[image]

Comment: First question: why are you saving full path in database, save only filename,and  cause you are using fixed path to photo '/uploads/photos',  in your template use '<img src="/uploads/photos/<?= $applicant->getPhoto()" />'

Comment: @waldek_c I tried your suggestion but it will only output the full path to the photo ,not the picture itself.

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand your question, if you want to display photo in edit action, fix template in file widget like: `'template' => '<div class="sublabel"><img src="%file%" /><br />%input%<br />%delete% %delete_label%</div>'`